# How to run `cplex` in high priority in a script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cplex

Want to run `cplex` in high priority in a script.

[This FAQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400068) is helpful to run cplex in the script. `cplex < cplexCommands.txt` starts `cplex` in the same window and run with commands from `txt` file. But for changing priority if I try to use `START "" /High cplex < cplexCommands.txt` it opens cplex in high priority but does not run the commands, moreover it creates a new window. `START "" /High cplex -f cplexCommands.txt` this opens `cplex` in high priority and runs the commands from `txt` but creates a new window.

How to get the same effect as running `cplex < cplexCommands.txt` command (i.e., without opening a new window) with high priority?

Comment: `start "" /b /wait /high cplex < "cplexCommands.txt"`

Comment: @sst thank you. This works.